# Unity 3D: Instantiate GameObject to specific position on the Parent

Tags: unity-game-engine, position, parent-child, parent, children

Newbie here. I want to Instantiate a GameObject to a specific position on the Parent. I want to place it at the top of the parent. Can I position it immediately when I instantiate it or do I need to use the transform.position? In either case I don't know how to do it. I also need to figure out how to rotate the child on the parent if you are feeling generous with your time. Also, each child/copy or new instantiated object will scale with each new iteration. I'm trying to build a reverse fractal tree (the branches get bigger over time).

Just a warning - you might cringe at other parts of the code that probably could be written better.

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform Cube;
    public GameObject masterTree;
    public int instanceCounter = 1;
    public int numCubes = 30;
    public float scalar = 1.4145f;
    public float initialScale = 10f;
    public float angle = 30f;
    private Transform copy;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (instanceCounter <= numCubes)
        {
            if (instanceCounter == 1)
            {
                copy = Instantiate(Cube, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
                copy.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, initialScale, 1f);
                copy.name = "Copy" + instanceCounter;
                copy.transform.parent = masterTree.transform;
                instanceCounter++;
            }

            var copyParent = GameObject.Find("Copy" + (instanceCounter - 1));
            Vector3 copyParentSize = copyParent.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size;
            Debug.Log("copyParentSizeY = " + copyParentSize.y);

            copy = Instantiate(Cube, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);

            copy.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, initialScale, 1f);
            initialScale = initialScale * scalar;
            copy.name = "Copy" + instanceCounter;

            //copy.transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(angle, angle, 0);
            copy.transform.parent = copyParent.transform;
            instanceCounter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `I want to place it at the top of the parent.` What do you mean exactly? To the same position or above the parent object? Also what exactly do you mean by `I also need to figure out how to rotate the child on the parent`? Could you maybe add a picture of the desired result .. it's a bit hard to imagine it. Since you parent the objects you can simply assign their `transform.localPosition` and `transform.localRotation` with the desired offsets to the according parent object

Comment: Thanks derHugo for your clarifying questions! When I say I want to place it at the top of the parent I mean that if the parent is a tall cylinder I want to stack the child on top of the cylinder like boxes stacked on top of each other. As for rotation I want to be able to rotate the child on that "connection point" where the parent and child connect. I think transform.localPosition and transform.localRotation is the way to go, I just can't seem to wrap my head around how they work exactly in the code.

Comment: As said I think an illustration of how your expected result would look like (paint, screenshot of correctly placed objects in unity, etc) would really help to figure out what exactly your needs are

Comment: I seem to need more points to add images. Here's a link to what I'm trying to accomplish: http://jonathangibson.com/unity/moving.png I want to be able to do this with and without parenting.

Comment: Here's a video of what I'm getting when I parent the objects to each other: http://jonathangibson.com/unity/unity2.m4v
I'm using copy.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 1.5F, 0); to change their position.

The spacing is not precise between the children. I think this is because of the scaling? Also I don't understand how hinge points work.

Answer (score 1):

If I understands your needs right...
There is a Instantiate method with Parent parameter, so you can create new GO as a child of your parent

```
public static Object Instantiate(Object original, Transform parent);
```

If you want to have some kind of pivot, you can create empty GameObject in your target parent, shift it to right position and instantiate your GO as a child of that empty GO.

Also you can wrap your Cube in another empty GameObject (ex: position 0,0,0), so you can shift Cube up (0,5,0), but origin of whole GameObject remains same (0,0,0).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! This is very helpful. I think as I think through my problem a bit more I realize that I just want to be able to move one instantiated GO in relation to another instantiated GO. Sometimes that will be the parent and sometimes that will be another unrelated GO.  I'll definitely try this: "Also you can wrap your Cube in another empty GameObject (ex: position 0,0,0), so you can shift Cube up (0,5,0), but origin of whole GameObject remains same (0,0,0)."

Comment: Here's a link to what I'm trying to accomplish. I want to be able to do with with parenting and without parenting. http://jonathangibson.com/unity/moving.png

Comment: Here's a video of what I'm getting when I parent the objects to each other: http://jonathangibson.com/unity/unity2.m4v
I'm using copy.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 1.5F, 0); to change their position.

The spacing is not precise between the children. I think this is because of the scaling? Also I don't understand how hinge points work.

Answer (score 0):

I understand Vector3 better now. It looks like I can add together different GameObject positions together in the same Vector3:

```
newPosition = new Vector3(0, copyParentSize.y + copyParentPosition.y + spacer, 0);
```

Now I move objects around based on the location of other objects. 
Thank you for your help!